Problemas con código angular al actualizar http.post
estoy tratando de actualizar mi código de angular 9 a angular 18
` this.http.post(url_api, {tipo:"login", Usuario:user.Usuario, Clave:user.Clave},
    {headers: Cabecera})
    .subscribe(data=>{
      switch (data[0].Estado) {
        case "-1":
           alert("¡Algo ha salido mal!, La contraseña ingresada no es válida para el usuario");
        break;
        case "0":
          // alert("¡Algo ha salido mal!, El usuario ingresado no se encuentra registrado en el sitema");
          
          break;
        default:
          user.Id = data[0].Id;
          user.Tipo = data[0].Tipo;
          user.Usuario = data[0].Usuario;
         
          this.loggedIn.next(true);
         alert('Bienvenido ' + user.Usuario + ", espere un momento a que se cargue el sistema.");
          this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      }
    });
  }
`

Este código funcionaba bien en angular 9, ahora que estoy actualizando me sale este error:
switch (data[0].Estado) {
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(7053)

¿alguien me puede ayudar con la solución?
intenté establecer
.subscribe((data:Object)=>{
   data[0].Estado //<-- igual esto bota error
}


Puedes corregirlo creando un tipo para esos datos:
export type Data = {
  Id: number;
  Tipo: string;
  Usuario: string;
  Estado: string;
}

Luego asignarle el tipo correspondiente a los datos recibidos en la petición:
.subscribe((data:Data[])=>{
   data[0].Estado
}

